# myPage.com instead of mypage.com/WebContent

Tags: apache, html, web-hosting, webproject

I have created my webpage in eclipse as `Dynamic Web Project` and uploaded the `WebContent folder` to the `server` (`WebContent` contains `index.html js, imgs and css`). When I call `myPage.com`, it works only with the url `myPage.com/WebContent`. Afterthat I have uploaded the content of the `folder WebContent` directory to the `server root`. Now when I call `myPage.com`, it display empty page. `mypage.com/index.html` display empty page too.

How to upload `WebContent`, sothat the `index.html` display woithout using `WebContent` in the `url`?

Comment: what's the content of index.html ? it should work in root

Comment: well... I know :D but maybe links to external files are wrong etc, that's why I'm asking for content, not content type ;)

Comment: but why mypage.com/WebContent works?

Comment: @KristopherPeter can you post your index.html file (or link us to the example) and post your apache config?  If it doesn't work with the files copied to the DocumentRoot, you either have some paths that aren't correct or there's something going on with your conf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by:

- Using URLRewrite. This thing changes URLs according to the patterns you configure. More to read: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/rewrite.html
- Using redirects in the root folder - if someone requested the folder, it automatically sends you to another folder. This can be done by placing `index.html` in root folder containing: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://mypage.com/WebContent" />`;
- Using [Virtual Host](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html) - description for Tomcat 6.

Comment: why do you recommend workarounds rather than solution ?

Comment: @Alexey Malev: can you explain one of these methods?

Comment: @KristopherPeter Added details